# Crystal and Operational Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, crystal

I'm studying the attached circuits made up from a RLC network (with a Crystal) and an operational amplifier.

I've never used crystal with OPA. How does this OPA configuration work?

[image]

Comment: What is off to the left? It looks like a secondary winding but is there a primary? What is the BW of that "opamp"? link to its datasheet. One hint : crystals are narrowband resonant circuits. That means they can be used as filters, as well as oscillators. The opamp circuit itself looks perfectly straightforward.

Comment: You must have a reason to study this so what is it that you are studying i.e. where did the circuit come from? Can you use a simulator? This is your tenth question and you haven't formally accepted any answers yet - is there a reason?

Comment: Looks like a bandpass filter; interestingly, the open loop amplifier gain at 20M is about 20dB, which is the gain set by the feedback resistors, so the high frequency rolloff is achieved by both the (rather low) Q of the crystal *and* the falling open loop gain of the amplifier itself.

Comment: Is the some reason you need an analog output from an RX coil without specs?